# How does 2.0 + 3.0 = 4.0 using a 5-bit floating point representation based on the IEEE format and round-to-even?

Tags: floating-point, ieee

I am confused as to how 2.0 + 3.0 = 4.0 when rounding-to-even for this IEEE-based format of representing floating point numbers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8LIR.jpg

Specifically the last part. The second to last one is also slightly confusing.

Could I please have an explanation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.0 is represented as 1.0 E 1 (1 * 2^1) (I'm writing mantissas in base 2.)

3.0 is represented as 1.1 E 1 (3/2 * 2^1)

Adding them together, you get an unnormalized mantissa of 10.1, which gets normalized to 1.01, and the exponent becomes  2^2.  But because there is only room to represent 1 decimal place of the mantissa, we have a choice between using 1.0 and 1.1 for the mantissa, and round-to-even says we choose the "even" mantissa, which gets us to 1.0 E 2 (1 * 2^2, or 4.0).

Comment: The question said "rounding-to-even" not truncation. Of course, they have the same effect in this case.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: "rounding to even", in this context... does it mean "Assume the least significant bit is always zero (i.e., even), and hence we can omit it"? (i.e., represent the number using one bit less than before)

Comment: @NicolasMiari No, because 1.0 + 0.10 == 1.1 with no rounding.